# Contact form below pager

Tags: html, web, blogger

I decided to make a contact form on my blog.

When I type a block of text my block of text will be above the text. However, when I insert a contact form, the contact form goes below the pager. I coded the code for the contact form right after the code for the block of text, but for some reason it's under the pager, why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Here's the page I'm talking about: http://hereandlost.blogspot.ca/p/contact.html

I'm not that experienced in HTML, and I can't seem to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your pager is part of your "Blog" widget. Your contact form is a separate widget that is inserted outside the scope of the "Blog" widget and inserted below it. To fix this you will need to have this form inserted into the blog widget itself above the pager... or move it with some script. I would try inserting the html into the contact page body content itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by adding the given simple code to your blogger page via html method.

Fist goto p/contact.html this page then write it as html method which is in near to 'compose' button and paste the following code and save the page.

```
<div class='footer section' id='footer4'>
        <div class='widget ContactForm' id='ContactForm1'>
            <div class='contact-form-widget'>
                <div class='form'>
                    <form name='contact-form'>
                        <p></p>Name<br/><input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
                        <p></p>Email<span style='font-weight: bolder;'>
                                                      *
                                                    </span>
                        <br/>
                        <input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
                        <p></p>
                        Message
                        <span style='font-weight: bolder;'>
                                                      *
                                                    </span>
                        <br/>
                        <textarea class='contact-form-email-message' cols='25' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' rows='5'></textarea>
                        <p></p>
                        <input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Send'/>
                        <p></p>
                        <div style='text-align: center; max-width: 222px; width: 100%'>
                        <p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'></p>
                        <p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```